# Is $ [(A \Rightarrow C) \land (B \Rightarrow C)] \Leftrightarrow [(A \lor B) \Rightarrow C]$ true?

Tags: logic

> Is it true that the two statements are equivalent:
>
> $A$ implies $C$ and B implies $C$, $(A \Rightarrow C) \wedge (B \Rightarrow C)$;
>
> $A$ or $B$, implies $C$, $(A \lor B) \Rightarrow C$;
>
> where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are statements?

My attempt of a truth-table suggests so (T means true, F false).
[image]

As with my [last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3349593/integral-of-x2-4-x-2-x2-2-x-with-respect-to-x), I, with no profound mathematical knowledge whatsoever, stumbled across this issue trying some issues just for fun (now from "How to prove it", Velleman 2006). One solution for an exercise gave $[(A \lor B) \Rightarrow C]$. I arrived at $[(A \Rightarrow C) \wedge (B \Rightarrow C)]$ (The problem reads: "If $x$ is divisible by either 4 or 6, then it is not prime."). Now, I would like to know, if I went wrong, which is likely, in particular, as I am having a hard time to get my head around the "implies"-operator. As I do not know how to show equivalence of statements, I thought to give a truth-table a try.

If equivalence indeed holds: Is there a law? Blindfoldly generalizing, it seems, logical connectives get flipped.

---

Edit: 
Due to the [comment by Ronald Wong](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3603089/702349) (thank you), I now also tried the following; 
$(A \Rightarrow C) \wedge (B \Rightarrow C)$ 
$ \Leftrightarrow (\neg A \lor C) \land (\neg B \lor C)$ 
Then, maybe we can use distributive laws to "factorize" C; 
$ \Leftrightarrow (\neg A \wedge \neg B) \lor C$ 
Next, it might be time for one a the very few laws I could recall: DeMorgan's law; 
$ \Leftrightarrow \neg (A \lor B) \lor C$ 
Finally, we do the same thing as in the beginning; 
$ \Leftrightarrow (A \lor B) \Rightarrow C.$

Comment: [Here you go.](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#%20((A%20%E2%86%92%20C)%20%E2%88%A7%20(B%20%E2%86%92%20C))%20%E2%86%94%20((A%20%E2%88%A8%20B)%20%E2%86%92%20C))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

[image]

[Here](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#%20((A%20%E2%86%92%20C)%20%E2%88%A7%20(B%20%E2%86%92%20C))%20%E2%86%94%20((A%20%E2%88%A8%20B)%20%E2%86%92%20C)) is a link to the software I used.

This is known as the [method of analytic tableaux](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux).

Comment: I find this amazing, thank you! Will for sure prove handy to check suggestions.

Comment: You're welcome, @Sinistrum.

Answer (score 1):

In propositional logic, yes, the are equivalent.

You can check it directly by the table. Or actually in propositional logic, the symbol $\Rightarrow$, $\Leftarrow$ and $\Leftrightarrow$ can be expressed by the combination of $\land$, $\lor$, $\neg$

i.e. $A \Rightarrow B$ actually equivalent to  $\neg(A \land \neg B)$

and $\neg (A \land B)$ is equivalent to $\neg A \lor \neg B$

you may be able to check them easily when you get away all the arrows

Comment: Thank you very much! I added an attempt to my question.